# Cloudify nodecellar,Task failed 'script_runner.tasks.run' -> RecoverableError('ProcessException: ',)

Tags: cloudify

when I try to install nodecellar with Cloudify,I am getting the following error

```
    2015-07-13T17:31:03 LOG <nodecellar> [mongod_a50aa.configure] ERROR: Exception raised on operation [script_runner.tasks.run] invocation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/cloudify.host_dba5c/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/decorators.py", line 125, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/cloudify.host_dba5c/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/script_runner/tasks.py", line 58, in run
    return process_execution(script_func, script_path, ctx, process)
  File "/root/cloudify.host_dba5c/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/script_runner/tasks.py", line 74, in process_execution
    script_func(script_path, ctx, process)
  File "/root/cloudify.host_dba5c/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/script_runner/tasks.py", line 143, in execute
    stderr_consumer.buffer.getvalue())
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is raised by the Cloudify Script Plugin you ran a script, which exited with a non-zero error code. [Here is the source of that error](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-script-plugin/blob/1.2/script_runner/tasks.py#L153).

The script that returned non-zero code is that script which is mapped to the configure operation on the mongod node. Which script that is depends on the version of the Nodecellar blueprint that you are using.

I can't give a more detailed answer without information regarding the specific blueprint version, which Cloudify version you have installed, details about your provider (local, Vagrant, Openstack, AWS), and OS (Ubuntu, Centos, etc).

Comment: I installed Cloudify 3.1,OS is Ubuntu Server 12.04,provider is local,I solved this problem already,It's a proxy problem in my case. But now I get another problem(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396092/deploying-nodecellar-in-cloudify-nodecellar-cant-start).Please help me..