# Deploying nodecellar in Cloudify,nodecellar can't start

Tags: cloudify

```
2015-07-14T02:33:19 LOG <nodecellar> [nodecellar_e32b8.start] INFO: [GET] http://localhost:8080 404
```

2015-07-14T02:33:20 LOG  [nodecellar_e32b8.start] INFO: Nodecellar has not started. waiting...
2015-07-14T02:33:21 LOG  [nodecellar_e32b8.start] INFO: [GET] http://localhost:8080 404
2015-07-14T02:33:21 LOG  [nodecellar_e32b8.start] INFO: Nodecellar has not started. waiting...
2015-07-14T02:33:22 LOG  [nodecellar_e32b8.start] INFO: [GET] http://localhost:8080 404
2015-07-14T02:33:22 LOG  [nodecellar_e32b8.start] INFO: Nodecellar has not started. waiting...

Cloudify can't start the nodecellar node...A proxy problem???

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error.

During the install workflow the agent [regularly checks](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-nodecellar-example/blob/3.2/scripts/nodecellar/start-nodecellar-app.sh#L46) to see if the application is started. If the application did fail to start you would see [this error](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-nodecellar-example/blob/3.2/scripts/nodecellar/start-nodecellar-app.sh#L51):

"http://localhost:8080 failed to start. waited for a 120 seconds."

Or the install workflow might time out. In which case, there could be an issue with a proxy, or it may be something else. However, given the log you've provided it's impossible to say.